# "%" in $(wildcard) not expanded?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to encode the the rule "to make `<name>.done`, you need all files of the pattern `<name>.needed.*`. I've attempted to write this with this Makefile:

```
%.done: $(wildcard %.needed.*)
    cat $^ > $@
```

Yet when I run `touch foo.needed.bar && make foo.done`, all I get is

```
cat  > foo.done
```

It appears the `%` inside `$(wildcard)` is being interpreted as a literal "%". How can I get it expanded to the right value ("foo" in this case)?

Comment: `widcard` -> `wildcard` presumably

Comment: Explanation why it doesn't work: the recipe parameters (source, input and dependencies) are evaluated/expanded already during parsing, thus `$(wildcard)` is invoked with literal `%`, finds no files, and is replaced with empty string. Delayed evaluation is only applied to the command. FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` is just a placeholder for "any string" in pattern matching.  It has no special meaning in the `wildcard` function and is interpreted literally.

You might attempt using `$*` instead (which would expand to the stem of the filename), but unfortunately it won't work either:

```
%.done: $(wildcard $*.needed.*)
```

The reason it doesn't work is that the *automatic variables* (`$*` is one of them) are not available for use in the dependency list.

The workaround is to request a [*secondary expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) for the target:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.done: $$(wildcard $$*.needed.*)
```

This will prompt GNU Make to go over the rule a second time after processing the Makefile as usual, expanding any escaped variables that weren't expanded the first time around.  The second time around, the automatic variable have their appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. Also, someone commented earlier with a simpler but less general solution: `%.done: %.needed.*`.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn Well, that would work in some cases, but if you're using `$<` or `$+` or something in the commands for remaking the target, it may pick up the wrong files.